# Programmatically add a comment line to an XML object in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, comments

I'm creating different XML files programmatically with XML; which works perfectly fine. To give potential readers of those XML files additonal hints, I want to add descriptive comment lines with the "", so those lines are highlighted correctly in e.g. notepad++ or sublime pro.

I could append a comment node like this is a description
But then that comment isn't highlighted as comment.

I tried several ideas like escaping the angle brackets, including the comment into a CDAT construct which was wrapped in a new XML element, ...

But nothing worked the way I want.

In short:
How to create a structure like this in AS3:

```
`<node1>content node1</node1>
<!-- add your sub nodes here -->
<node2>content node2</node2>`
```

**UPDATE/Solution**:
Thanks to @akmozo I finally solved my problem.
My mistakes have been:

1. Bug in IDE Editor

I trusted my IDE telling me the statement was wrong, which stated "an expression was expected". So I not even started my program; what was a mistake. 
Only after I wanted to get a more detailed error message I could post as answer and started the program, it surprisingly worked without any more warnings or errors!

2. Incorrect XML.ignoreComment use

I missed the 
    XML.ignoreComments = false;
statement; or more precisely: I used incorrectly added an ignoreComment property to my xml object instead of using it as a property of the XML class ;-(

My working test lines look like this:

```
var myNode:XML = <book />;
var pgNbr:String = "10";
var pgCount:String = "50";
var commentLine = "<!-- This is page #:" + pgNbr + ", out of " + pgCount + " pages -->";
XML.ignoreComments = false;
myNode.appendChild(new XML(commentLine));
```

And the result is perfect!

```
<book>
   <!-- This is page #:10, out of 50 pages -->
</book>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an XML comment as any other XML child, in your case you can use [`insertChildAfter()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#insertChildAfter()) like this for example :

```
// to see your added comment
XML.ignoreComments = false;

var xml:XML = <data>
    <node1>content node1</node1>
    <node2>content node2</node2>
</data>;

xml.insertChildAfter(xml.node1, <!-- add your sub nodes here -->);

trace(xml.toXMLString());
```

gives

```
<data>
    <node1>content node1</node1>
    <!-- add your sub nodes here -->
    <node2>content node2</node2>
</data>
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning insertChildAfter; I did not consider that.
I tried this:

`    actNode.appendChild(<test>test node</test);
    actNode.insertChildAfter(actNode.test, <newNode>new</newNode>);`

This worked and created the tree as expected:

`<actnode>
    <test>test node</test)
    <newNode>new</newNode>
</actnode>`

But trying to add a comment as you proposed like this:

`actNode.insertChildAfter(actNode.test, <- comment ->)`

I get a compiler error: "Expression expected"

Comment: @hnuecke I used `insertChildAfter()` just to add the XML comment after the 1st child, otherwise, `addChild()` can do the job also ... If you did it correctly that should work without any problem : `var actNode:XML = <actnode><test>test node</test><newNode>new</newNode></actnode>; actNode.insertChildAfter(actNode.test, <!-- comment -->);` ...

Comment: @BotMaster
I added the final solution to my original post so it is better readable.
Based on your and mainly akmozo's input I found my perfect solution; thank you very much!
That was a fast ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you cannot when working with XML and XMLList objects. The good news is, you can when working with string. So take your XML, convert to string, add your comment then convert back to XML. Sounds like too much to do? Well that's what you have to do in most programming languages when adding comments to XML.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation; that's what I assumed. But I wanted to be on the safe side ;-)
Since I intend to comment different nodes with comments containing dynamic data, this would be a too big effort doing kind of XML parsing and inserting strings with embedded variables at string level.
So I will give up the idea of nicely highlighted comment lines and add comments as "real" XML nodes

Comment: @hnuecke No that's wrong. You can add an XML comment to an XML object as any other XML child.